# Вычисление данных в сгруппированном Data Frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Есть два DF:

```
df_estim = pd.DataFrame({'estim': ['est1', 'est2', 'est3'],
                   'title': ['title1', 'title2', 'title3'],
                    'key': ['key1', 'key2', 'key3'],                   
                   'mount': [300.15, 350.85, 400.47],
                   'equip': [870.35, 1750.59, 1830.80]})
df_estim


    estim   title   key     mount   equip
0   est1    title1  key1    300.15  870.35
1   est2    title2  key2    350.85  1750.59
2   est3    title3  key3    400.47  1830.80
```

```
df_equip = pd.DataFrame({'sys_2': ['sys1', 'sys1', 'sys1', 'sys1', 'sys1', 'sys1', 'sys2', 'sys2', 'sys2', 'sys2',
                                   'sys2', 'sys2', 'sys2', 'sys2', 'sys3', 'sys3', 'sys3', 'sys3', 'sys3', 'sys3',
                                  'sys3', 'sys3'],                    
                    'block_2': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                                1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2,
                               2, 2],
                    'kks_2': ['kks1', 'kks2', 'kks3', 'kks4', 'kks5', 'kks6', 'kks7', 'kks8', 'kks9', 'kks10',
                              'kks11', 'kks12', 'kks13', 'kks14', 'kks15', 'kks16', 'kks17', 'kks18', 'kks19', 'kks20',
                             'kks21', 'kks22'],
                    'key': ['key1', 'key1', 'key2', 'key2', 'key3', 'key3', 'key1', 'key1', 'key2', 'key3', 
                            'key3', 'key2', 'key1', 'key1', 'key2', 'key2', 'key3', 'key2', 'key3', 'key2',
                           'key3', 'key3'],
                    'price_2': [100.10, 110.10, 120.10, 130.10, 140.10, 150.10, 160.10, 170.10, 180.10, 190.10, 
                                200.10, 210.10, 220.10, 230.10, 240.10, 250.10, 260.10, 270.10, 280.10, 290.10, 
                                300.10, 310.10]
                           })
df_equip[:5]


    sys_2 block_2 kks_2 key     price_2
0   sys1    0   kks1    key1    100.1
1   sys1    0   kks2    key1    110.1
2   sys1    0   kks3    key2    120.1
3   sys1    0   kks4    key2    130.1
4   sys1    0   kks5    key3    140.1
```

Для дальнейшего объяснения делаю объединение:

```
merge_df = pd.merge(df_equip, df_estim,  how='inner', left_on='key', right_on='key', 
                    left_index=False)
merge_df[:5]


    sys_2 block_2 kks_2 key     price_2 estim   title   mount   equip
0   sys1    0   kks1    key1    100.1   est1    title1  300.15  870.35
1   sys1    0   kks2    key1    110.1   est1    title1  300.15  870.35
2   sys2    1   kks7    key1    160.1   est1    title1  300.15  870.35
3   sys2    1   kks8    key1    170.1   est1    title1  300.15  870.35
4   sys2    2   kks13   key1    220.1   est1    title1  300.15  870.35
```

Нужно из полученных вспомогательных данных (ниже):

```
merge_df.groupby(['estim', 'equip'])['price_2'].sum()

estim  equip  
est1   870.35      990.6
est2   1750.59    1690.8
est_3  1830.80    1830.8
```

вычислить отношение по каждой записи `estim` между данными колонки `equip` и `['price_2'].sum()`, и поместить их в колонку `coeff` (например, для `est1`: `870.35/990.6 = 0.8786`). Коэффициент необходим для расчета данных в новой колонке `estim_sys`. Порядок расчета для `est1`: сумма `['price_2'].sum() / коэффициент для est1 = 0.8786`. Итого: `239.24`:

```
merge_df.groupby(['sys_2', 'block_2', 'estim'])['price_2'].sum()

sys_2  block_2  estim   estim_sys
sys1   0        est1     239.24       210.2
                est2                  250.2
                est3                  290.2
sys2   1        est1                  330.2
                est2                  180.1
                est3                  390.2
       2        est1                  450.2
                est2                  210.1
sys3   0        est2                  490.2
                est3                  260.1
       1        est2                  270.1
                est3                  280.1
       2        est2                  290.1
                est3                  610.2
```

И еще прошу подсказать, как сохранить результаты (`['price_2'].sum()`) в стационарную колонку, например `cost_equip`, что бы к ней можно было обращаться.

Comment: можете показать в вопросе тот датасет, который вы хотите получить на выходе?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
m = merge_df.copy()         
m["coeff"] = m["equip"] / m.groupby(['estim', 'equip'])['price_2'].transform("sum")
res = (m
       .groupby(['sys_2', 'block_2', 'estim'])
       .apply(lambda x: x["price_2"].sum() / x["coeff"])
       .reset_index(name="estim_sys"))
```

---

```
In [32]: res
Out[32]:
   sys_2  block_2 estim  level_3   estim_sys
0   sys1        0  est1        0  239.241822
1   sys1        0  est1        1  239.241822
2   sys1        0  est2        6  241.654619
3   sys1        0  est2        7  241.654619
4   sys1        0  est3       14  290.200000
5   sys1        0  est3       15  290.200000
6   sys2        1  est1        2  375.821359
7   sys2        1  est1        3  375.821359
8   sys2        1  est2        8  173.948829
9   sys2        1  est3       16  390.200000
10  sys2        1  est3       17  390.200000
11  sys2        2  est1        4  512.400896
12  sys2        2  est1        5  512.400896
13  sys2        2  est2        9  202.924203
14  sys3        0  est2       10  473.457611
15  sys3        0  est2       11  473.457611
16  sys3        0  est3       18  260.100000
17  sys3        1  est2       12  260.874951
18  sys3        1  est3       19  280.100000
19  sys3        2  est2       13  280.191867
20  sys3        2  est3       20  610.200000
21  sys3        2  est3       21  610.200000
```

---

> Как образовалась колонка "level_3"?

в столбце `level_3` - значения оригинального индекса из `merge_df` DataFrame.

> Как правильно добавить колонку "estim_sys" из "res" в "m"?

здесь мы как раз можем использовать столбец "level_3", чтобы Pandas смог выровнять данные по индексам при присваивании:

```
In [42]: m["estim_sys"] = res.set_index("level_3")["estim_sys"]

In [43]: m
Out[43]:
   sys_2  block_2  kks_2   key  price_2  ...   title   mount    equip     coeff   estim_sys
0   sys1        0   kks1  key1    100.1  ...  title1  300.15   870.35  0.878609  239.241822
1   sys1        0   kks2  key1    110.1  ...  title1  300.15   870.35  0.878609  239.241822
2   sys2        1   kks7  key1    160.1  ...  title1  300.15   870.35  0.878609  375.821359
3   sys2        1   kks8  key1    170.1  ...  title1  300.15   870.35  0.878609  375.821359
4   sys2        2  kks13  key1    220.1  ...  title1  300.15   870.35  0.878609  512.400896
5   sys2        2  kks14  key1    230.1  ...  title1  300.15   870.35  0.878609  512.400896
6   sys1        0   kks3  key2    120.1  ...  title2  350.85  1750.59  1.035362  241.654619
7   sys1        0   kks4  key2    130.1  ...  title2  350.85  1750.59  1.035362  241.654619
8   sys2        1   kks9  key2    180.1  ...  title2  350.85  1750.59  1.035362  173.948829
9   sys2        2  kks12  key2    210.1  ...  title2  350.85  1750.59  1.035362  202.924203
10  sys3        0  kks15  key2    240.1  ...  title2  350.85  1750.59  1.035362  473.457611
11  sys3        0  kks16  key2    250.1  ...  title2  350.85  1750.59  1.035362  473.457611
12  sys3        1  kks18  key2    270.1  ...  title2  350.85  1750.59  1.035362  260.874951
13  sys3        2  kks20  key2    290.1  ...  title2  350.85  1750.59  1.035362  280.191867
14  sys1        0   kks5  key3    140.1  ...  title3  400.47  1830.80  1.000000  290.200000
15  sys1        0   kks6  key3    150.1  ...  title3  400.47  1830.80  1.000000  290.200000
16  sys2        1  kks10  key3    190.1  ...  title3  400.47  1830.80  1.000000  390.200000
17  sys2        1  kks11  key3    200.1  ...  title3  400.47  1830.80  1.000000  390.200000
18  sys3        0  kks17  key3    260.1  ...  title3  400.47  1830.80  1.000000  260.100000
19  sys3        1  kks19  key3    280.1  ...  title3  400.47  1830.80  1.000000  280.100000
20  sys3        2  kks21  key3    300.1  ...  title3  400.47  1830.80  1.000000  610.200000
21  sys3        2  kks22  key3    310.1  ...  title3  400.47  1830.80  1.000000  610.200000

[22 rows x 11 columns]
```

Comment: @MaxUСпасибо, как всегда на уровне!
Подскажите пожалуйста:
1) Как образовалась колонка "level_3"?
2) Как правильно добавить колонку "estim_sys" из "res" в "m"?

Comment: @MaxUСпасибо!
То что надо!!!